# Gamma and Delta vs Dual Gamma and Dual Delta

Tags: options

My understanding is that the dual delta is generally lower than the delta across all strike prices (they still have the same asymptotes at 0 and 1 for a call), primarily because options are often utilized for hedging. Consequently, buyers are inclined to pay a premium above the fair value. Therefore, relying on delta rather than dual delta to estimate the likelihood of an option expiring in the money tends to exaggerate this probability. Is this correct?

When comparing gamma to dual gamma as a proxy for the distribution of the underlying asset is there generally a pattern? (e.g dual gamma higher than gamma for upside strikes and lesser for downside strikes)

Thanks so much in advance and apologies if I'm being dumb :)

Comment: Please define the concepts, or provide references. Are you talking about the first and second derivatives of an option price (formula or empirical) w.r.t. the underlying price and the strike?